# Django url parsing error

Tags: django, django-urls

OK,
I have two different views, both in the project site-wide area.

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'taxo.views.login'),
url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'taxo.views.invalid'),
...
```

taxo/views.py

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)
def invalid(request):
    return render_to_response('invalid.html',{'title':'invalid'})
```

templates/login.html

```
<form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <label for="username">User name</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
   <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

templates/invalid.html

```
<form style="float: right" action="accounts/login/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form}}
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="search"/>
</form>
```

With the above code, I got Page not Found error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/invalid/accounts/login/
```

Django parses the requested url as relative to the url of the current page. When I replaced the action with the `{% url %}` tag.   I got a **NoReverseMatch at /accounts/invalid/** error

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: looks like you concat both url endpoints into 1 url

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form style="float: right" action="/accounts/login/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form}}
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I did but got the -  NoReverseMatch at /accounts/invalid/
Reverse for '/accounts/login/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] instead.

Answer (score 0):

And here's the reason:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/invalid/accounts/login/
```

$ at the end of regex means nothing's after slash:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'taxo.views.login', name='login'),
url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'taxo.views.invalid', name='invalid'),
```

therefore you may use those urls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/invalid/
```

edit:
why one of your URLs in template redirects begins with slash and one without? Try this one:

```
<form style="float: right" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: When I tried that. I got the NoReverseMatch exception:  Reverse for '/accounts/login/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Comments can't display the code, so I edited the answer. Check changes in urls.py and in template - it's more elegant.